# MySQL select statement not finding the column by name, what am I missing?

Tags: mysql, select

I have an MYSQL database with one table in it and I am trying to look up records by one of the columns. I thought this would be straight forward, but I am getting an error when I try and look up my data with a select statement.

Here is an image of my database columns.
[image: database columns]

I thought the issue was with my code but then decided to run the query from the command line interface.
Here are three examples of slightly different queries I have run. Where I am trying to return an item by its PLU number. 
[image: select statments]

I have renamed the column, tried changing the data type to INT and Text, and had the same result. Not really sure what I am missing.

Comment: Check again the name of the column for leading or trailing spaces, maybe something like ``plu ``

Comment: It's also probably worth checking for control characters, the fact the column information for plu is offset compared to the rest makes me suspect MySQL padded the Field column by character length but didn't account for one of the characters being non-printing.

Comment: I double-checked in MYSQL Workbench and no leading or trailing spaces seem to exist. Oddly if I coy the column name from MYSQL Workbench and past it into the Command line, the SQL will run correctly even though is still says exactly the same thing. Maybe an OS issue.

Comment: Try `SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(COLUMN_NAME), COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'pluDataSeed';`; if "plu" comes back with something other than 3, there is probably a non-printing character hidden in it somewhere.

Comment: As @Uueerdo mentioned I think it has something to do with control characters but I'm not really sure how to fix it, This is on my development environment, maybe I will just wire up a database on a server and use that.

Comment: You can see in the 1st image that you posted that the only column name that is not aligned vertically correctly is plu.

Comment: Using workbench, you might be able to rename the field to something else and then back, the fact you could copy it out of workbench makes it hopeful that selecting name and replacing it will replace the problem character as well. Alternatively, you could create a new table with the correct names, copy the data over with an insert-select, and then remove the old table and rename the new one.

Comment: Yup It's a hidden Cheracter, thanks for helping me figure that out. @Uueerdo

Comment: Summarized my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like this to help identify hidden character and leading/trailing spaces.

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(COLUMN_NAME) AS nameLen, CONCAT('[',COLUMN_NAME,']') AS name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'myTableName'
;
```

If such problems are found, you can try to rename the problem field(s) via MySQL Workbench (or PhpMyAdmin, or whatever RDBMS tool you use).

However, if that fails *(perhaps it is at the beginning or end and the text control used for the field name can't "grab" the character)*, you can create an empty copy of the table, with the correct field names in the same order, and then use `INSERT INTO copy SELECT * FROM original` (explicitly omitting the field names to avoid potential problems, which is why "same order" is important). Then just drop the original and rename the copy.

*If there are foreign keys referencing the original, they will also need dropped before the rename, and recreated after.*

Comment: This helped a lot, I ended up recreating the table and that corrected the issues. I had to be extra careful because my data came from excel spreadsheets. Great learning experience.

Comment: It's great that you found the solution. Excel sheets may contain ' symbol added to number to preserve leading zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * from pluDataSeed WHERE plu = '3345'` is the correct syntax. Have you checked that you are using the apostrophe marks and not some other form of upticks? It looks like there's some mangled character messing up your query.
(That mangled character might also be in the database column name)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like there's a "backspace" character (or some other non-ASCII or non-printable character) in the column name.

We can inspect a hexadecimal representation of the column name.  We will assume the garfed charcacter is before of after the `plu` characters

```
SELECT c.column_name
     , HEX(c.column_name)
  FROM information_schema.columns c 
 WHERE c.table_schema     = DATABASE()
   AND c.table_name       = 'pluDataSeed' 
   AND c.column_name   LIKE '%plu%'
```

We could leave the last condition off, to get all of the columns in the table. Or just add another condition to pick out the column, e.g.

```
   AND c.ordinal_position = 1
```

We could also try using

```
 SHOW CREATE TABLE `pluDataSeed`
```

That should get us back a usable column name enclosed in backticks. (With non-ASCII characters, the character sets of the database and the client are going to come into play with characterset translations.)

We could do an `ALTER TABLE` statement to rename the column, but we are going to have to get the current name of the column into the statement. Copying from the `CREATE TABLE` statement might do the trick.